# Change field2 when field1 change in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form, which it ask for the field1 a serial number. Then in the 2nd field, it will ask the model. But I can find the model with the serial number. Its the 3 & 4th numbers of the serial. So instead of asking the model number, I wanted to put directly the model without the user intervention.

I want the field2 directly changed when the field1 has been updated, not after the post of the form.

So first, is it possible only with php ? My knowledge in jQuery, Ajax and JS are very limited.

Here's how I'm doing now :

```
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="no_serie_produit" class="label col-xs-3">N° Série Produit</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="text"  name="no_serie_produit" id="no_serie_produit" placeholder="N° Série de ... (Obligatoire) ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model_produit" class="label col-xs-3">Modele Produit</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text"  name="model_produit" id="model_produit" placeholder="Modèle ... (Obligatoire)">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

2nd : If I really need to use something like JS or jQuery, can you suggest me the most easy one to learn.

**EDIT**

Example :

If I put in Serial n° : 14020001,  I want in the field2 : TMSA4-NET LV

Comment: It is technically possible to do with only PHP, but that'd require a form submission which you probably don't want.

Comment: Yes, i forget to precise that point. I want the change in "live" :D

Comment: The only way to change it in 'real time' is to use a client side scripting language like JavaScript, but i would recommend learning the JQuery library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event on `#no_serie_produit`, then set the value of `#model_produit` accordingly:

```
$('#no_serie_produit').on('input', function() {
    // don't do anything before 4 digits are inputted
    if (this.value.length < 4) return;

    // .slice()'s start is inclusive, end is exclusive
    var modelId = this.value.slice(3, 5);

    // do the Ajax call with $.ajax or the shorthand $.post/$.get methods
    $.get('path/to/getModelName.php', { modelId: modelId }, function(modelName) {
        // received the model name in the Ajax response, update the field
        $('#model_produit').val(modelName);
    });
});
```

This will send an Ajax request to `path/to/getModelName.php` (update the path/filename accordingly), in this PHP file you will be able to access the model ID through `$_GET['modelId']`. Then you can query the database with it and `echo` the name. The echoed value  will be returned as the response of the Ajax call, that is, the `$.get`'s callback's `modelName` parameter in this case.

Some reading reference:

- [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)
- [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
- [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: I guess I need to install and configure Ajax/jQuery with your solution ?

Comment: Oh wait, I might have misread your question. Let me see, you need to send the 3rd and 4th digit through Ajax to retrieve the product name?

Comment: Yes, the 3 and 4 number of the serial n° refers to a full name model. Ex : Serial n° : 14020001 where "02" refers to Model : TMSA4-NET LV.

Comment: @Booba__2012 I've updated the code and added some explanation about the server-side implementation. `=]`

Comment: Ok thx mate, I never have work with Ajax but I will give a try with your code ^^

Comment: No problem. `=]` If you want to do some quick and dirt testing, just `echo "something";` (or `echo $_GET['modelId'];`) to ensure that the JS is working as it should (passing a value to PHP and receiving a response back).